# How to scrape "th" data from another website in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, web-scraping

I want to copy one value from another website, which is in `th` and `anchor` tag. I want to store this value in my application, I'm able to get h3/h2 data but not `<a>` data.

below is the html/f12 of other website. from this i want to extract 1,945 which is in bottom anchor.

```
<tr class="zebra">
<th>Total Backlinks</th>
<td>
<span class="tooltip-from-element" data-tooltip-position="lefttop" data-target-position="rightmiddle" data-tooltip-id="tooltip_overview_total_backlinks" name="total_backlinks">
<a onclick="ClearInfoAndDataTable();" href="/xyz.com?target=www.homeocare.in">1,945</a>
</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

I'm using this code to get that data:

```
string url = txthack.Text.Trim();
        string strurl = "https://mywebsitedomains?target= " + url + ""; //&warning=0&profile=css2";

        StreamReader stream = objm.URLServerRequest(strurl);

        string myResponse = stream.ReadToEnd();

       MatchCollection AltTag = Regex.Matches(myResponse, "(<h3.*?>)(.*?)(</h3>)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
         string s = AltTag[1].ToString();
```

Comment: what do you wanna get? can you please write down exactly? value of 1,945?

Comment: i want to get 1.945 value which is coming in other website i want to get that data .one anchor tag value has 1,945. i want to get all anchor tags from that i want to get my value

Comment: Use `@"(?s)(?<=<a\s[^<]*?>).*?(?=</a>)"`. Verbatim string literals are useful in C# when defining regex patterns.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Regex is not very suitable for web scraping or similar tasks, as [Val Nolav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784715/val-nolav) suggested there are libraries particular useful for such scenarios, [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) and [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) are two well known libraries in this section.

here is a little example of using CsQuery (syntax is compatible with jquery selector) to extract strings from `h3`, `h2`, `th` and `a` tags.

```
        var cq = CsQuery.CQ.Create(@"<tr class=""zebra"">
                <th>Total Backlinks</th>
                <td>
                <span class=""tooltip-from-element"" data-tooltip-position=""lefttop"" data-target-position=""rightmiddle"" data-tooltip-id=""tooltip_overview_total_backlinks"" name=""total_backlinks"">
                <a onclick=""ClearInfoAndDataTable();"" href=""/xyz.com?target=www.homeocare.in"">1,945</a>
                </span>
                </td>
                </tr>");

        var texts=cq["th,a,h3,h2"].Select(a => a.InnerText).ToList();
```

CsQuery can be obtained through Nuget command `Install-Package CsQuery -Version 1.3.4`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to capture value inside  tag with RegEx, however, if you need scraping data out of websites in your project, I would recommend you to use HTMLAgilityPack.

```
  string a = "<a onclick=\"ClearInfoAndDataTable();\" href=\"/xyz.com?target=www.homeocare.in\">1,945</a>";
  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(<a[^>]*>)(.[^<]*)");
  string rs = "(<a[^>]*>)(.[^<]*)";

  System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(a, rs);
  Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
```

Comment: this is not my requirement , i want o get the value "1,945" dynamically , what ever it will be there that should come. my aim to get that value by web scraping